# how do I save Jquery_ui sortable position in rails?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi All~ I'm very new to rails and stockoverflow, so forgive my beginner lvl questions.  (I'm nowhere near a Jquery/JS/ajax veteran either)

I know "save sortable list" question exists, but they are either catered for PHP, incomplete, or doesn't fit the propose of my project, I tried to seek out an comprehensible example all over the place, so far without any luck. 
(I'm using rails 5.0 & ruby 2.2)

My goal is to make a sortable list with Jquery_UI for a rails project where user refresh the page, the sorted content should be stay where they last stored, I know there are many ways to do this, ideally done by ajax request, cookies, post request aren't bad either.

So far the sortable function itself was easy enough, but when I tried to save their last position, I find myself struggling on rails' worklogic along.

What I completed 
1. confirmed my Jquery_ui code for sortable list worked (without my broken Ajax)
2. using "serialize" and make a ajax request(through not sure if my codes were correct)

what I'm confused at
3. In building my Ajax request, I know I need to link my rails controller's method to Ajax URL in order to send the data to my DB(or should I at all?) but what I can't seen to find is how to write this method to make my controller response to ajax?

or is my thinking process incorrect? I thanks everyone who can help a clueless noob.

My HTML

```
  <table>   
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>lead</th>
      <th>note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
     <% @user.each do |user| %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.location %></td>
      <td><%= user.lead %></td>
      <td><%= user.note %></td>

    </tr>

    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

my Jquery code

```
$("tbody").sortable(

  update: function(event, ui){


  axis: 'y',
  update: function (event, ui) {
    var order = $("tbody").sortable('serialize');
    $.ajax({
      data: order,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/projects/save_position',
      success: function() {
        console.log("does it work?")
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Path in rails controller to Jquery ajax -> Projects

> def save_sortable
>
> ```
> order = param[:tbody]     # ????? don't know how to write this method
> ```
>
> end

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 now requires Ruby 2.2.2 or greater per https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-5 which is a year old post. Ruby 2.3.1 seems to be what is being used as a minimum with Rails 5

Comment: Hi! sorry for my delayed response, thought my question won't be answered.   Due all respect, I don't think this answer is related to my question, i'm using ruby V2.3.3 and rails5, I was having trouble to store sorted order into array so when users reset the request, they can have sorted lists stay exactly where they were last time.